# IntelliJ Maven Selenium Build jar

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jar, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 12, Java 7, Selenium 2.31.0 and Maven. I can run my tests out of the IDE just fine but I am running into a problem trying to create a jar file. I can create the jar file double clicking on mvn clean and then double clicking install. All is well and the jar is created. The problem occurs when I go to run the jar via command line.

java -jar xyz-selenium-test-1.0.jar

Returns: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

I have added selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar as a library in the project settings and as a dependency module in the project settings. I must be missing something in my pom file but I just don't know what it is. I have also attached my pom file as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xyz.selenium.test</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-selenium-test</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>xyz-selenium-test</name>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.31.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.31.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.31.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>selenium-jar</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar</artifactId>
<version>2.31.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>/usr/local/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.31.0</version>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.7</source>
<target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
<archive>
<index>true</index>
<manifest>
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
<mainClass>com.setup.test.Setup</mainClass>
</manifest>
<manifestEntries>
<mode>development</mode>
<url>${project.url}</url>
<key>value</key>
</manifestEntries>
</archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add your dependencies to the classpath when you run your program:

```
java -cp "selenium-java.jar:..." -jar xyz-selenium-test-1.0.jar
```

Maven also allows you to [run a `Main` class with all the required dependencies](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/) in the classpath (see option 1 in the previous link).

Otherwise you can create a [Jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/500478), which will contain everything you need to run your code:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.setup.test.Setup</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and run

```
java -jar xyz-selenium-test-jar-with-dependencies-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed! I don't have enough reputation to up this but thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the OneJar plugin

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <onejarVersion>0.97</onejarVersion>
                        <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                        <!-- Optional, default is "onejar" -->
                        <classifier>onejar</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```